# Problems selecting an option with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, cypress

I'm facing an issue while handling dynamic IDs using the Cypress Automation tool. I have provided the statement below to tick/select the checkbox.

**DOM**

[image: Error1]

**Error**

[image: Error2]

I need to click on the options, and if I put it by ID it fails because it's dynamic.

I need to click on the options, and if I put it by ID it fails because it's dynamic.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here.

Answer (score 1):

After opening the dropdown, use the text of the option to select it

```js
cy.get(selector-for-dropdown).click()                 // open dropdown
cy.contains('[role="option"]', 'Supervisor').click()  // select an option by text
```